# Owasp ZAP Proxy Secure Connection Failed / err_empty_response

Tags: proxy, zap

after installing Zap Proxy on my Win 11 machine I tried simply connecting to localhost:8080 where by default the proxy should be running. I tried this on Firefox and Chrome and got Secure connection failed or Err_empty_response.

I used the bat file to start zap proxy since it would not start via the exe.
Version: 2.12.0

I already flushed my DNS and deinstalled WSL on my windows machine.

Comment: Can you connect to the site from the same machine using Firefox or Chrome when not proxying through ZAP?
Do you have to go through a corporate proxy in order to access them?

Comment: Hi, 
I was not able to get to it also  if I was not proxying through it, it could be that I had some miss configuration after a fresh install of Owasp Zap and Firefox it was working. But then as soon I wanted to proxy through Firefox I got a connection refused error. After I removed WSL on my Windows machine everything was working perfect . 
Thanks for the response @SimonBennetts